# vite Internal server error: Unable to parse HTML; parse5 error code missing-whitespace-between-attributes

Tags: html, reactjs, react-native, vue.js, mern

## I created a vite using tailwindcss project and ran

`npm run dev`

## This is the error message from my terminal

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PNai6.png)

### this is the index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html >
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <link rel="icon" type="image/svg+xml" href="/vite.svg" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="stylesheet"href="https://rsms.me/inter/inter.css">
    <title>aadda</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <script type="module" src="/src/main.jsx"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message points out that your code is missing a whitespace between attributes. I can see that your second `<link>` tag inside the `<head>` is really missing a whitespace between the `rel` and `href` attributes. Try adding the whitespace: `<link rel="stylesheet" href=" https://rsms.me/inter/inter.css">`